# C# Entity Framework NotMapped Unit Converter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework with a SQL-Lite Database to save my values. I have a lot of models where I need to use Units. Everytime a unit from a value is changed, the value gets converted. I don't want to write every convertion in the setter of each unit.

#### My sampleModel

```
public double? DiameterD { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public static UnitsNet.Units.LengthUnit DiameterDBaseUnit { get => UnitsNet.Units.LengthUnit.Millimeter; }

[NotMapped]
private LengthUnit? _DiameterDUnit;

[NotMapped]
public UnitsNet.Units.LengthUnit? DiameterDUnit
{
   get => this._DiameterDUnit ?? DiameterDBaseUnit;
   set
   {
       double convertedValue;

       UnitsNet.UnitConverter.TryConvert(
            this.DiameterD.Value,
            this._DiameterDUnit,
            value,
            out double convertedValue);

       this.DiameterD = convertedValue;
       this._DiameterDUnit = value;
   }
}
```

so in fact I want to have something like this;

**UnitValue class**

```
public double? Value {get; set;}

public System.Enum? BaseUnit { get; set; }

private System.Enum? _Unit {get; set; }

public System.Enum? Unit  
{
   get => this._Unit ?? BaseUnit;
   set
   {
       double convertedValue;

       UnitsNet.UnitConverter.TryConvert(
            this.Value.Value,
            this._Unit,
            value,
            out double convertedValue);

       this.DiameterD = convertedValue;
       this._DiameterDUnit = value;
  }
```

and in my database-models;

```
public static UnitValue.Value DiameterD {get; set;}

[NotMapped]
public static UnitValue.BaseUnit { get => UnitsNet.Units.LengthUnit.Millimeter; }

[NotMapped]
public static UnitValue.Unit { get; set;}
```

Maybe there are some best practices out there to realize that. I also dont want to create a new table in my database.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [EF Core's Value Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

```cs
// in your DbContext class
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<SampleModel>()
        .Property(x => x.DiameterD)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.As(LengthUnit.Millimeter),
            v => new Length(v, LengthUnit.Millimeter));
}
```

---

I created a library to help with this: https://github.com/gojanpaolo/UnitsNet.EntityFrameworkCore
Then you could refactor your code like so:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SampleModel>(builder =>
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.DiameterD).HasConversion(LengthUnit.Millimeter);
        builder.Property(x => x.SpeedS).HasConversion(SpeedUnit.KilometerPerHour);
    });
}
```